# How does Docker AUFS persist data?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have some doubts about how docker AUFS persists data. As i understand, data inside **VOLUME** can be persistent and others location can not. Here made an example, pull a mysql container whose [dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/5.7/Dockerfile) there and do below steps:

1. make a `test` directory under `/opt` directory which shouldn't be persistent in docker container
2. login mysql and create a database, so `/var/lib/mysql` directory added one additional file
3. stop such container and start again
4. commit such container and then remove the container
5. start the committed container and check whether database still exitst

**Result**

- After step 3, all exists inside container including `test` directory
  which i think shouldn't be persist in `AUFS`. So whether all i know about docker aufs is wrong?
- After step 5 i can see database not exists in new container, but why? shouldn't file inside `/var/lib/mysql` be persist?

**Here is my running docker command**

```
docker build -td --name mysql_test mysqlImageId
```

***Attention***: i have not specified `-v` options

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding of docker, I would expect the following results from the process steps that you have described:

**First up:** data **can** be persisted in docker containers - in fact any operation on your container that creates, deletes or updates files, will trigger *AUFS* to write that file into the *container layer*. For deletes or updates this will hide entries for the same files in lower *image layers*. Of course any data written only lasts until you remove the container. If you start a new container based on the same image, this data will naturally not exist.

**Also,** the purpose of docker build is to build images from a Dockerfile. You can't use it start a container.

Regarding your observations

- **After step 3** I would expect all your data to still be there, since stopping and restarting a container leaves the container layer untouched. The *stop* merely kills the main process that keeps your container alive and the *start* rekindles the main process by executing the relevant entry point script.
- **After step 5** I still expect your data to be there, since you have committed the container to a new image. This image should now include the modified container layer. When you call *docker commit*, keep in mind that this is not updating the original image but creates a new one.

Comment: I'd add to this that containers are somewhat "fragile" in that there several routine operations (changing port or volume mappings, updating the underlying image) that require deleting and recreating the container.  So if some datum lives _only_ in a container, it will probably eventually get lost.